# How to run C++ executable in Windows PE?

Tags: c++, .net, c++-cli

I have an executable I made using a CLI console application with Visual Basic 2010. I can run the program completely fine from my developer machine.

However, when I copy the executable over to another machine, re-boot to a pre-installation environment and run the executable again, nothing happens at all. There are no errors shown or anything.

My guess is the executable can't run without certain dependencies that aren't loaded at this environment, but I need it to work in a PE.

Any ideas on whats going on?

Comment: Are you in Release mode, or Debug mode? Because if you're in Debug mode, that could be a problem.

Comment: good idea! I was in debug. ill switch and try again

Comment: .NET isn't supported in a Win PE environment...

Comment: ok.. if .NET isn't supported, then how else can I get some Process classes into an application for use in PE?

Comment: Is this question really has to be tagged "C++" and "C++/CLI"? Or am I missing something? Isn't this about "Visual Basic" and ".NET"?

Comment: To add to this... I can run Powershell in PE just fine.. doesn't that require .NET as well?

Comment: @MattHintzke: Dude, everybody wants Linux! But seriously, I think you should remove the "C++" flag, at the least. This will only help you, by the way, since it will attract the people with the right sort of expertise here.

Comment: @MattHintzke, if you're used to Linux and C++, why don't you create a Win32 C++ application? What exactly are you using that requires .NET?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, since the question is tagged "c++" and you mention C++/CLI several times, I assume that "Visual Basic 2010" is a typo for "Visual Studio 2010". But either way, whether you've written the application in Visual Basic (VB.NET) or C++/CLI, the problem is exactly the same.

> My guess is the executable can't run without certain dependencies that aren't loaded at this environment, but I need it to work in a PE.

That's exactly correct. You've written an application that targets the [.NET Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework). Somewhat like Java applications requiring a JVM, .NET applications require that the .NET Framework be installed in order to run (or a compatible alternative implementation, like [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Start)). Unfortunately, Windows PE [does not support the .NET Framework](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766093.aspx).

Note that it is irrelevant whether you've written a WinForms, WPF, or Console application. Although they present their UI in very different ways, they *all* depend on the .NET Framework being installed.

You will need to (re-)write the application in a different programming language, one that generates native code without any dependencies on the .NET Framework. C and C++ are popular choices. If you choose to use C++, make sure that you create what Visual Studio calls a "Win32" project. This is one that targets the underlying operating system APIs directly (i.e. a native application) and does not have a dependency on the .NET Framework. Stay away from anything that has ".NET" or "CLR" in its description.

> I don't really have a full comprehension of when an application is using .NET or not... I am just used to Linux C/C++ development. I hate Microsoft shit

It uses .NET whenever you use the .NET Framework libraries/classes in your code. I'm not really sure why this is so difficult to understand. The same problem could easily exist on Linux if you were using a third-party library that was not available in certain environments for whatever reason. This is not Microsoft's problem, it's an issue of using the wrong tools for the job. The .NET Framework is an object-oriented wrapper around the native APIs that makes it much easier for people to get up and running writing programs for Windows. But if you're "used to Linux C/C++ development", you should have little trouble writing a simple console application that targets the native APIs directly without using .NET.

If your hatred for "Microsoft shit" has turned into an allergy, you can avoid Visual Studio entirely and download [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/), which is a Windows port of the GCC compiler you're probably used to. Combined with your favorite Windows port of Vi, you're working in an environment very similar to the one you're used to. And since GCC doesn't support C++/CLI or the .NET Framework, you won't have to worry about getting stuck picking the wrong option.

Answer (score 1):

The .Net framework has been supported as an optional package install during your PE build process for the past couple versions of WinPE. I write code in C# that I run in WinPE everyday. I have yet to find a good way to debug in a manner where I can walk through break points, etc... though. My best option has just been a lot of logging and a global Exception catch around my main entry point that will write out a full stack dump. You can attach to your app as a remote process in a VM running WinPE, but if you need to catch something early in the execution you'll have a difficult time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The last part of this answer should probably be extracted to a new question by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button; you may want to include a link to this one for context.

Comment: I agree - I have found logging and judicious use of exception management to be the most effective way of debugging in winpe w/ .Net. Looking for better answers, but haven't found any yet. The turn around - building and deploying winpe is a bit of a pain.