# std::cout inside main() not printing anything in debug console during debugging

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

Any cout statement inside main function is not printing any value during debugging but cout inside other functions are printing values during function call  (I use vscode )

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int a;
a=9;
if(a==9)
{
cout<<"hello";}
return 0;
}
```

when this is debugged placing a breakpoint on the first line of main()
"hello" is not printed in the debug console.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void fun(int n)
{
if (n > 0)
{
    cout << n << endl;
    fun(n - 1);


}
}

int main()
{
int x = 3;
fun(3);
cout<<x;
return 0;
}
```

but when this is debugged by placing a breakpoint in the first line of main()
values are printed like
3
2
1

Comment: How are the "other functions" printing? Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to improve it, for example by adding a [mcve].

Comment: In case there is a function call inside main and it is called and a cout exists inside it...that cout is printing a value

Comment: I suspect that the printing in `main` is after the function call and your function never returns.

Comment: @KaranarjunJr. Could you provide an example?

Comment: Please don't describe the code, *show* it to us instead. As I already mentioned, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) might be helpful as well. And some actual stepping through the code statement by statement in the debugger.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i have made edits now check out please . and btw i debugged by stepping line by line only

Comment: You already has an answer which is telling you to add std::endl or std::flush. Exactly that is missing! Why you write it didn't work if your code still has this problem?

Comment: @Klaus I have tried that..but didn't work..that's why I pasted my actual code for further help

Comment: So you're saying that `cout<<"hello" << endl;` doesn't work either? Perhaps it could be a VSCode buffering issue then?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I mean when I build and run the program ...cout is working fine but when I debug and go line by line any cout statement inside main function isn't printing any value in the debug console

Comment: Am using gcc compiler. Added "-static" flag and it worked. See [this so ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58789865/1977871)

Answer (score 0):

std::cout is buffered. Try to use std::flush or std::endl.

Also you can try to use std::cerr instead std::cout.

Comment: Am using gcc compiler. Added "-static" flag and it worked. See [this so ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58789865/1977871)